# Using Actors to exploit cores

Tags: scala, actor

I'm new to Scala in general and Actors in particular and my problem is so basic, the online resources I have found don't cover it.

I have a CPU-intensive, easily parallelized algorithm that will be run on an *n*-core machine (I don't know *n*).  How do I implement this in Actors so that all available cores address the problem?

The first way I thought of was to simple break the problem into *m* pieces (where *m* is some medium number like 10,000) and create *m* Actors, one for each piece, give each Actor its little piece and let 'em go.

Somehow, this struck me as inefficient.  Zillions of Actors just hanging around, waiting for some CPU love, pointlessly switching contexts...

Then I thought, make some smaller number of Actors, and feed each one several pieces.  The problem was, there's no reason to expect the pieces are the same size, so one core might get bogged down, with many of its tasks still queued, while other cores are idle.

I noodled around with a Supervisor that knew which Actors were busy, and eventually realized that this has to be a solved problem.  There must be a standard pattern (maybe even a standard library) for dealing with this very generic issue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [Akka](http://akkasource.org/) library, which includes an implementaton of actors. The [Dispatchers Module](http://doc.akkasource.org/dispatchers-scala) gives you more options for limiting actors to cpu threads (HawtDispatch-based event-driven) and/or balancing the workload (Work-stealing event-based).

Answer (score 3):

You should look into Futures I think. In fact, you probably need a threadpool which simply queues threads when a max number of threads has been reached.

Here is a small example involving futures: http://blog.tackley.net/2010/01/scala-futures.html

I would also suggest that you don't pay too much attention to the context switching since you really can't do anything but rely on the underlying implementation. Of course a rule of thumb would be to keep the active threads around the number of physical cores, but as I noted above this could be handled by a threadpool with a fifo-queue.

NOTE that I don't know if Actors in general or futures are implemented with this kind of pool.

For thread pools, look at this: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/ThreadPoolRunner.html

and maybe this: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/actors/scheduler/ResizableThreadPoolScheduler.html

Good luck

**EDIT**

Check out this piece of code using futures:

```
import scala.actors.Futures._

object FibFut {
  def fib(i: Int): Int = if (i < 2) 1 else fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fibs = for (i <- 0 to 42) yield future { fib(i) }
    for (future <- fibs) println(future())
  }
}
```

It showcases a very good point about futures, namely that *you* decide in which order to receive the results (as opposed to the normal mailbox-system which employs a fifo-system i.e. the fastest actor sends his result first).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, there're 2 kinds of actors: those that are tied to threads (one thread per actor), and those that share 1+ thread, working behind a scheduler/dispatcher that allocates resources (= possibility to execute a task/handle incoming message against controlled thread-pool or a single thread).

I assume, you use second type of actors - event-driven actors, because you mention that you run 10k of them. No matter how many event-driven actors you have (thousands or millions), all of them will be fighting for the small thread pool to handle the message. Therefore, you will even have a worse performance dividing your task queue into that huge number of portions - scheduler will either try to handle messages sent to 10k actors against a fixed thread pool (which is slow), or will allocate new threads in the pool (if the pool is not bounded), which is dangerous (in the worst case, there will be started 10k threads to handle messages).

Event-driven actors are good for short-time (ideally, non-blocking) tasks. If you're dealing with CPU-intensive tasks I'd limit number of threads in the scheduler/dispatcher pool (when you use event-driven actors) or actors themselves (when you use thread-based actors) to the number of cores to achieve the best performance.

If you want this to be done automatically (adjust number of threads in dispatcher pool to the number of cores), you should use **[HawtDisaptch](http://hawtdispatch.fusesource.org/)** (or it's **[Akka implementation](http://doc.akkasource.org/dispatchers-scala#Dispatchers%20%28Scala%29-Types%20of%20dispatchers-HawtDispatch-based%20event-driven)**), as it was proposed earlier:

> The 'HawtDispatcher' uses the
>   HawtDispatch threading library which
>   is a Java clone of libdispatch. All
>   actors with this type of dispatcher
>   are executed on a single system wide
>   fixed sized thread pool. The number of
>   of threads will match the number of
>   cores available on your system. The
>   dispatcher delivers messages to the
>   actors in the order that they were
>   producer at the sender.

Answer (score 0):

For any significant project, I generally have a supervisor actor, a collection of worker actors each of which can do any work necessary, and a large number of pieces of work to do.  Even though I do this fairly often, I've never put it in a (personal) library because the operations end up being so different each time, and the overhead is pretty small compared to the whole coding project.

Answer (score 0):

[Be aware of actor starvation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127711/how-to-prevent-actor-starvation-in-the-presence-of-other-long-running-actors) if you end up utilizing the general actor threadpool. I ended up simply using my own algorithm-task-owned threadpool to handle the parallelization of a long-running, concurrent task.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming Scala 2.9 is expected to include parallel data structures which should automatically handle this for some uses.  While it does not use Actors, it may be something to consider for your problem.

While this feature was originally slated for 2.8, it has been postponed until the next major release.

A presentation from the last ScalaDays is here:

http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/140