# IO/Network-bound Fork/Join-Tasks

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, deadlock, task

I am using an unbounded, thread-caching Java-ExecutorService which concurrently processes my tasks.
Now I have some tasks that do just some lengthy operations (the minority) and some tasks that do blocking IO (connecting to an URL, the majority).
If running my application and starting one workload, about 70 tasks are dispatched to the executor which fires up 70 threads and processes all of them concurrently.

I want to limit the threads per host that the task wants to connect to and if possible, also the number of overall tasks. My problem is that all tasks do something like fork-join, so they spawn other tasks and wait for their result before proceeding. This means I can't just use a semaphore or a bounded-queue per host, since a tasks could fork other tasks which won't get processed until the semaphore/queue has a free slot, thus the application is deadlocked.

Is there some pattern to approach this problem?

**Refined**: IO(=network)-bound Tasks are submitted. After doing some IO-work they potentially fork other IO-Bound tasks, then join them and, potentially, do additional IO-bound processing.

This seems to be Fork/Join with IO-bound Tasks. How do I limit/throttle the execution of IO-performing tasks without deadlocking the thread that initially forked the tasks (deadlocked because its forked child-tasks won't get processed due to limits/throttling) ?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Would the thread-pool concept be of any use? I'm not sure I fully understand the issue at hand, but it seems like you are looking for a way to constrain thread creation but in a controlled fashion. Thread pools (perhaps a number of them) may help.

Comment: Are you sure that there should be `scala` tag?

Comment: cdeszaq, yes I think i must use several thread-pools and control their thread-creation. getting complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async is definitely the way to go, as they compose very nicely. While the programming model is painful in Java, using [Finagle](http://twitter.github.com/finagle/) on top of Netty is a breeze with Scala, where all operations are basically a function that takes a Request and returns a Future[Response] that can be mapped (transformed) across.

See also:

- http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/finagle.html
- https://github.com/twitter/finagle

Comment: Finagle looks very nice but it seems to be a combinator-wrapper around normal Futures/Promises-Semantics, so they have a blocking-behaviour and as such cannot help me?

Comment: In Finagle you generally don't do anything with the Future on the original thread, you pass functions that are called on the thread that is processing the result. The shape of most things is the function A => Future[B] not A => B, the framework deals with the Futures.

Comment: I had a deeper look into finangle, especially their normal twitter-util Future and it looks impressive. Very nice code and async behaviour, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use the scala actor library? 
There you can also limit the thread pool size if you want to use pools. try that:
[How to designate a thread pool for actors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597899/how-to-designate-a-thread-pool-for-actors) .

Comment: I know the actors and erlang well but I think the MPI approach does not fit my task-submitting problem. It's rather Fork/Join than MPI

Comment: @hotzen by the way, initial implementation of scala actors were swapped with akka which (by default) uses fjp underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think your problem is solvable in general. If I understand correctly, you want to submit some tasks to a thread-pool which is **limited in its number of threads**, right? then, each task may block for IO, submit some additional tasks, and **block again to join them**, right?

Well, I'm afraid that under these conditions deadlock is inevitable. All the thread-pool's threads may be occupied blocking in some task that is waiting for a "forked" task to run, but, of course, it can't because the pool is exhausted. There is no way around it other than allowing more threads to be created (an unlimited pool).

What you could do is throttle the submissions a bit during startup (sleep a little between each one is submitted to the pool).

Comment: yes, exactly. I am looking for some sort of pattern to control this. Or I'll have to kill the fork/joins and resort to some sort of asynchronous callbacks, which i'd like to avoid...

Comment: Well, then simply *don't* limit the number of threads. I think that Java thread-pools will eventually kill unused threads. As I said, if you don't want a slew of threads created in the beginning, try not to submit everything all at once. Alternatively, you might want to use a networking library, ([Netty](http://netty.io/) is a great choice) that can handle some of the threading/asynchronicity for you.